# Why did Voldemort lose consciousness during his second 'kill' of Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

Does the book specify why V lost his consciousness when he killed Harry as a Horcrux? Was it a mother's protection or simply the fact he just killed part of himself? (like "you suddenly lose a gallon of your blood" type of getting lightheaded)

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate of something but I can't find the question just now.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Trying to distract us from an embarrassing moment? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It isn't fully explained in the books, but it's likely because of the rebounding Killing Curse.**

The Dark Lord tried using the Elder Wand to cast Avada Kedavra on Harry Potter. That knocked both of them unconscious, but didn't succeed in killing either of them.

> “Harry looked back into the red eyes, and wanted it to happen now,
>   quickly, while he could still stand, before he lost control, before he
>   betrayed fear – He saw the mouth move and a flash of green light, and
>   everything was gone.” - *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 34 (The Forest Again)*

From the flash of green light and this conversation between Dumbledore and Harry, we can deduce that the spell the Dark Lord cast was indeed the Killing Curse.

> “He killed me with your wand.’
>
> ‘He failed to kill you with my wand,’ Dumbledore corrected Harry. ‘I
>   think we can agree that you are not dead – though, of course,’ he
>   added, as if fearing he had been discourteous, ‘I do not minimise your
>   sufferings, which I am sure were severe.” - *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 (King's Cross)*

The curse seems to have rebounded, and in doing so, hits both Harry (its intended target) and the Dark Lord. Both Harry and the Dark Lord lose consciousness, and get back up again before the final battle.

> “Voldemort seemed to be getting to his feet. Various Death Eaters were
>   hurrying away from him, returning to the crowd lining the clearing.
>   Bellatrix alone remained behind, kneeling beside Voldemort. Harry
>   closed his eyes again and considered what he had seen. The Death
>   Eaters had been huddled round Voldemort, who seemed to have fallen to
>   the ground. Something had happened when he had hit Harry with the
>   Killing Curse. Had Voldemort, too, collapsed? It seemed like it. And both of them had fallen briefly unconscious and both of them had now returned …” - *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*

Comment: That does lead to the question of what Voldemort saw, if anything, when he was unconscious. I don't remember that being mentioned, though it's been a while since I read the last book.

Comment: Adding to your answer I think that (in the books) we can rule out that the shock came from destroying the horcrux inside Harry since Voldy didn't feel the previous destruction of the other horcruxes.

Comment: @JAB: Probably not much, considering the miserable state he was in while in the limbo. He may have felt pain, though.

Comment: @chirlu: He could not *possibly* have seen much.  Narcissa told him that Harry was dead and he believed her.  So obviously he didn't see Harry and Dumbledore talking about how Harry was not dead.

Comment: @JAB That's a really interesting question! :) I just checked it, and there's nothing mentioned in the book (or the movie either) about what the Dark Lord saw while unconscious.

Comment: I don't really see any evidence that the AK rebounded in this instance from the quotes you've cited...

Comment: @TheDarkLord I thought that when you took in Harry's blood you tethered his life so that while that fragment was in Harry he could not die. But then you destroy it and you both seem to be unconscious. Could it be that that lingering protection from Lily's sacrifice was now also removed from you? I don't remember if Voldemort could have died while that was still in him and/or in Harry. If however it had to be destroyed in both of them perhaps it did rebound? Just a possible theory which might hold no soul (or blood or water if you prefer).